# How to retrieve new record in view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have 2 record in my table, like this picture:

[image]

then i insert 2 new record, but the new record doesn't appear in my view, i've checked in my table and the new record already saved.

[image]

Here is my **View**:

```
<?php
      foreach($dts121 AS $row_dts121) {
           $kode_sample[] = $row_dts121->kode_sample;
           $jam_sampling[] = $row_dts121->jam_sampling;
      }
      $no=-1;
      foreach($dtdetail as $detail) { 
           $no++; ?>

           <tr>
              <td>
                  <?php echo $kode_sample[$no];?></td>
              <td>
                  <?php echo $jam_sampling[$no];?></td>
           </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

The **controller**:

```
[.....] 
$dtdate            = addslashes($this->input->post('dtdate'));
$data['dtdate']    = addslashes($this->input->post('dtdate'));
$data['date']      = addslashes($this->input->post('dtdate'));
[.....]
$dts121 = $this->M_dts121->get_dts121($dtdate); 
$dtdetail = $this->M_formfrmfss121_01->get_detail_byid($id);

$data1 = array('dtdetail' => $dtdetail);
$data2 = array('dts121' => $dts121);

$this->load->view('form_input/V_form'.$frmcode.'_'.$frmvrs, array_merge($data, $data1, $data2));
```

And here is the **model** function:

```
var $tabel2 = 'tblfrmfrmfss121dtl';

function get_dts121($date) {
        $query = $this->db1->query("select a.detail_id, a.kode_sample, a.jam_sampling 
                                    FROM tblfrmfrmlqs083dtl a join tblfrmfrmlqs083hdr b ON a.headerid = b.headerid AND b.date_input = '$date'");
        return $query->result();
    }

function get_detail_byid($id) {
        $this->db1->from($this->tabel2);
        $this->db1->where('headerid', $id);
        $this->db1->where('stdtl','1');
        $this->db1->order_by("detail_id", "asc");
        $query = $this->db1->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { //old 1
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

I run the query manually its working, but only in my view the new record doesn't appear. How do i get each new record to appear in my view ?

Comment: What $date in your query?

Comment: follow this `insert` then `select` and then `show`

Comment: where did you insert? what table? `tblfrmfrmlqs083dtl`? or `tblfrmfrmlqs083hdr`?

Comment: `$date` is a parameter for the view, so when i click a date (ex: 2016-01-01) then function `get_dts121` will be execute to show the match record.   The record are inserted into table `tblfrmfrmlqs083dtl`. **Product code** = _kode_sample_ and **Sampling Time** = _jam_sampling_

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `array_merge()` just pass array to load view as:

```
$data["dts121"] =  $dts121;

$this->load->view('form_input/V_form'.$frmcode.'_'.$frmvrs, $data);
```